# Making safe a mass insert of data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-injection

I'm currently building an application that needs a feature to import a user-supplied CSV file as data into a database. Each "cell" in the CSV will be stored in its own row.

Initially I was using parameterized queries to insert each row one-by-one, but the speed of the operation (520,000 inserts in one example file!) meant I'm having to reconsider that. I'm now parsing the CSV file into an `IEnumerable<Answer>` and handing it over to the following code to be inserted into the database in batches:

```
    public void AddAnswers(IEnumerable<Answer> answers)
    {
        const int batchSize = 1000;

        var values = new StringBuilder();
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var answer in answers)
        {
            if (i++ > 0)
            {
                values.Append(",");
            }
            values.AppendFormat("({0},{1},'{2}')", answer.AnswerSetId, answer.QuestionId, answer.Value.Replace("'", "''"));

            if (i == batchSize)
            {
                // We've reached the batch size limit - send what we have so far
                SendAnswerBatch(values.ToString());
                values.Clear();
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            // Ensure any leftovers that didn't reach the maximum batch size are sent over
            SendAnswerBatch(values.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SendAnswerBatch(string values)
    {
        var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO Answers (AnswerSetId,QuestionId,Value) VALUES {0}", values);
        Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
    }
```

This changed a large set of data from taking over 5 minutes to less than 5 seconds to insert, however I realise that basic replacing of `'` with `''` is not safe.

Obviously the safest way to insert a single row would be to use a parameterized query but is there a way to make such a thing work with a batch insert like this?

If at all possible, I also need it to be non-database specific - I had already considered `SqlBulkCopy` but the application needs to support multiple database engines.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use sqlBulkCopy, when inserting a lot of values, this provided to be really usefull to me

place your items into a datatable and let SqlBulkCopy do the rest.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: Am I wrong in my thinking that `SqlBulkCopy` only supports SQL Server?

Comment: @GrahamWager Yes, SQLBulkCopy is SQLServer specific. There's an OracleBulkCopy if that helps at all, unsure about other RDBMS' : http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm